# Custom blocking queue locking issue

Tags: java, android, locking, queue, blocking

I am trying to do some custom implementation of blocking queue with fixed length array of byte arrays. I am not removing polled elements, therefore I adjusted put method to return byte array so that it can be written directly (producer thread uses MappedByteBuffer to write directly to this byte array). I added "commitPut()" method to simply increase counters and set "lengths" arrays. (if multiple threads would be writing this could be the concurrency problems, but I know that only one thread is writing).

Below is what I currently have. It works if I debug through step by step, but if I "run" it looks like it encounters some locking problems. I copied, stripped down and adjusted ArrayBlockingQueue code. Can someone with better knowledge please look at the class and tell me what I am doing wrong, or how to do it better (like write directy to buffer and set lengths array and counters at the same step)?

```
public class ByteArrayBlockingQueue {

    private final int[] lens; // array to valid lengths
    private final byte[][] items; // array of byte arrays

    private int takeIndex = 0;
    private int putIndex = 0;
    private int count = 0;

    public volatile int polledLen = 0; // lenght of last polled byte array

    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final Condition notEmpty;
    private final Condition notFull;

    final int inc(int i) {
        return (++i == items.length)? 0 : i;
    }

    public ByteArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, int size, boolean fair) {
        if (capacity <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.items = new byte[capacity][size];
        this.lens = new int[capacity];
        lock = new ReentrantLock(fair);
        notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
        notFull  = lock.newCondition();
    }

    public byte[] put() throws InterruptedException {
        final byte[][] items = this.items;
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            try {
                while (count == items.length)
                    notFull.await();

            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                notFull.signal(); // propagate to non-interrupted thread
                throw ie;
            }
            //insert(e, len);
            return items[putIndex];
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void commitPut(int lenBuf) throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            lens[putIndex] = lenBuf;
            putIndex = inc(putIndex);
            ++count;
            notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public byte[] poll() {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (count == 0)
                return null;
            final byte[][] items = this.items;
            final int[] lens = this.lens;
            byte[] e = items[takeIndex];
            this.polledLen = lens[takeIndex];
            //items[takeIndex] = null;
            takeIndex = inc(takeIndex);
            --count;
            notFull.signal();
            return e;

        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the "locking problems" you are encountering?

Comment: Seems like "producer thread" locks "consumer thread". I don't quite get these locks, although they seem good to me (almost the same principle as other build-in blocking queues). If I step through with a debugger, setting break points in "poll" and "put" - it works. I can see bitmaps (bytes in byte array) decode properly. As soon as I "run through" it fails (bytes cannot be decoded) - if I try to debug polled value, expression watcher fails with some "child update" error, so I assume it is a locking problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the queue wraps around, it is possible that byte arrays get reused and overwritten before having been read by consumers. In short, you'd need to have a `commitGet` method to make sure that producers wait for consumers before overwriting an array with new data.

However, my suggestion is that you rely on [java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) having a second queue to return them from consumers back to the producer, and on [java.nio.ByteByffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to keep track of lengths. The producer would do as follows:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = bufferQueue.poll(); // instead of your put()
buffer.put(source);                     // fill buffer from source MappedByteBuffer
buffer.flip();                          // set length to the amount written
dataQueue.offer(buffer);                // instead of commitPut()
```

The consumer would:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = dataQueue.poll();   // instead of your get()
buffer.get(...);                        // use data
buffer.clear();                         // reset length               
bufferQueue.offer(buffer);              // this is the missing commitGet()
```

You should initially insert `capacity` elements in `freeQueue`. Note however that this will still copy data once from the `source` buffer into temporary buffers in the queues, as your original code already did.

If you really don't want to copy data (and are sure that the source does not change until all consumers have read it!), your better option is to use a single blocking queue and insert buffers obtained with [ByteBuffer.slice()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice%28%29) from your source buffer for each chunk of data to be handed down to consumers. These will then be garbage collected, but should take much less memory than the byte arrays themselves.

Comment: thanks for helping out. Why I am trying to reuse byte arrays - before I was using simple ArrayBlockingQeueu with Bitmaps. I have producer that was filling the qeueu and consumer (drawer) consuming bitmaps. This was working, at least I thought, until I tried it on some "funny" low budget android tablet where GC is kicking in all the time for even smallest  allocations (in total I am using 10MB out of 48 allowed, so not even close to understand why GC is so aggresive on this tablet). For this reason I decided to try with fixed allocated byte array, reusing it and not giving GC reason start.

Comment: I see. Using a second queue to return empty arrays should do it safely.

Comment: I am still trying to wrap my head arround your two queue concept... Can you please explain it again? If I have producer "reader" which wants to read bytes from a MappedByteBuffer directly to "readers" queue (to avoid byte copying) and wait when queue is full, and consumer "drawer" which consumes bytes from the readers queue. Because byte arrays are fixed length (to accomodate largest bitmap) I still need to keep track of "byte lengths" for each queue slot.

Comment: I've updated the reply to use `ByteBuffer`. Note that your solution does not avoid copying, as it reuses byte arrays. A single queue with `slice()` will completely avoid copying.

Comment: I have found the problem in my original code - in poll() notFull.signal() happenes before "return" and producer starts filling new bytes before consumer processed "polled" ones. This lead to consumer processing 11th "frame of bytes" instead of 1st, but had length of 1st. At the moment I will just try to fix that code as I am comftable with it. But I will definately give your solution a go and try to wrap my head around it, also checking out slice(). This area is a bit new to me and will take some time to conquer. Thank you for you time and help!